# Can these two systems be equal?

Tags: quantum-mechanics

Suppose that there are two differents systems, $A$ and $B$, both associated with the same potential $V(x)$ (take, for instance, an infinite well). Then would the eigenstates of $A$ be the same as the ones of $B$?

I would say that they are, as the eigenstates for any potential are unique (I mean, they are functions after all). But I'm not sure, as they would belong to different Hilbert spaces, I believe. So that's my question: is $|\psi_n\rangle_A=|\psi_n\rangle_B\space\forall n$ true?

Comment: Yes? I'm not sure what you're asking; are you asking if identical wavefunctions in identical potentials have identical eigenstates, or are you asking whether wavefunctions are coupled by virtue of being in identical potentials?